# Is statement of account with 28days fund before Student UK visa application valid for UK Student visa application

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, passports, visa-refusals

I am Aminat,can I apply for my student UK visa application with the proof of fund account statement that I used to process my CAS after 28days of maturity or I need to drop my funds in the account till I get my student visa decision.Thanks

Comment: Usually UK visa applications ask you to send bank statements (meaning detailed lists of all your transactions), not proof of funds. What are you being asked to send?

Answer (score 1):

When you apply, you need to provide statements dated within the last 31 days of your application showing that you have the required funds, and have had them for at least 28 days.

Obviously those funds must be available to you and remain available to you during your stay in the UK to pay for your expenses. Once your visa am has been accepted and you are on the UK, as you pay for your expenses, it’s quite normal that those funds will reduce.

Even though they cannot check that the funds are still available after the date of the statement your submitted, obviously you shouldn’t be in a situation where those funds are no longer available to you after that point. For instance you cannot borrow the funds for the time required, then pay them back to whomever you borrowed it from. You need to have that money to pay for your expenses during your stay.

Comment: Thanks so much sir